# vector dentro de vector gera duplicidade de valores na segunda dimensão

Tags: c++, vector

No exemplo abaixo (que também pode ser visto no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/l1RXAE)), eu tenho um `vector` de uma classe e dentro da classe eu tenho um elemento também `vector`.

A questão é que ao fazer o `push_back` da classe, o vector interno `vetint` deveria começar do zero a cada `push_back` da primeira dimensão, mas c++ está mantendo os valores anteriores, daí o vetor vai se duplicando.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class classe
{
public:
    int var;
    vector<int> vetint;
};


int main()
{
    vector<classe> vetor;
    classe obj;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
        obj.var = (i+1)*10;
        for (unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
            obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
        }
        vetor.push_back(obj);
    }
    for (unsigned i=0; i < vetor.size() ; i++) {
        cout << "var(" << i << ") = " << vetor[i].var << endl;
        for (unsigned c=0; c < vetor[i].vetint.size() ; c++) {
            cout << "vetint(" << c << ") = " << vetor[i].vetint[c] << endl;;
        }
    }
}
```

Produz esse resultado:

```
var(0) = 10
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
var(1) = 20
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
vetint(3) = 100
vetint(4) = 200
vetint(5) = 300
```

Quando o desejado seria:

```
var(0) = 10
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
var(1) = 20
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
```

Por que isso acontece? Como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema acontece porque o método [`push_back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) copia o elemento `obj` através da execução de um construtor de cópia.

Um exemplo desse construtor seria:

```
// Construtor de cópia da classe
classe(classe const &c)
{
    var = c.var;
    vetint = c.vetint;
}
```

Portanto, o vetor `vetint` é copiado juntamente com os elementos que já estão nele, causando o problema da duplicidade de valores.

Uma solução possível é criar uma nova instância a cada iteração do *looping* que insere o objeto no vetor `vetor`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class classe
{
public:
    int var;
    vector<int> vetint;
};

int main()
{
    vector<classe> vetor;

    for(unsigned i=0; i<2 ; i++) {
        classe obj; // AQUI: cria uma instância nova a cada iteração

        obj.var = (i+1)*10;
        for(unsigned c=0; c<3 ; c++) {
            obj.vetint.push_back((c+1)*100);
        }
        vetor.push_back(obj);
    }
    for(unsigned i=0; i < vetor.size() ; i++) {
        cout << "var(" << i << ") = " << vetor[i].var << endl;
        for(unsigned c=0; c < vetor[i].vetint.size() ; c++) {
            cout << "vetint(" << c << ") = " << vetor[i].vetint[c] << endl;;
        }
    }
}
```

Após a execução, a saída ocorre conforme esperado:

```
var(0) = 10
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
var(1) = 20
vetint(0) = 100
vetint(1) = 200
vetint(2) = 300
```